# Django Get Foreign Key Value in Many-to-Many

Tags: python, django

relatively new to Django, so this is probably straightforward and just missing something. Given these models:

```
class Manager(models.Model):
    mgrname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
class Salesperson(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mgr_name = models.ForeignKey(SalesMgr,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class SalesList(models.Model):
    list_description = modesl.CharField(max_length=100)
    list_members = models.ManyToManyFiels('Salesperson')
```

Each salesperson is assigned a manager (only one - managers have many salepeople). My user can create an arbitrary contact list ("SalesList") which contains any number of salespeople (salespeople can belong to many lists.  A list may contain many sales people).

I'm able to retrieve a list of salespeople on a selected list, but I need to include the sales manager name.

How can I retrieve the manager name when the list is selected?

Thank you!

Comment: But now each `SalesList` can contain `Salesperson`s from *different* managers, right?

Comment: yes - that's correct.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply iterate over the `Salesperson` and access the `.mgr_name`, and then thus the `mgrname`, so for example:

```
sales_list = SalesList.objects.first()  # some SalesList record
for salesperson in sales_list.list_members.all():
    print((salesperson.name, salesperson.mgr_name.mgrname))
```

This will however make an extra query *per* `SalesPerson` in the list, which is not a good idea. You can use [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to fetch the manager object when we fetch the `SalesPerson`s:

```
sales_list = SalesList.objects.first()  # some SalesList record
for salesperson in sales_list.list_members.select_related('mgr_name'):
    print((salesperson.name, salesperson.mgr_name.mgrname))
```

---

> **Note**: A `ForeignKey` does *not* store the string representation (or name) of the
> referenced object in the column, it stores the primary key of the record it
> references in a column with an  `_id` suffix to a `ForeignKey` field. Therefore
> `ForeignKey`s usually do *not* end with a `_name` suffix. You might want to
> consider renaming the <s>`mgr_name`</s> field to `manager`.

Comment: got it -thank you for the advice! I know by default the many-to-many table is hidden.  Does this method require that table to be "exposed"?

Comment: @muttinthehut: well the m2m table itself is hidden, but that does not matter, since here we fetch a list of `SalesPerson` objects, so we query "through" the m2m table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an extra model and use 'through=new_model' in the ManytoManyField.

```
class Manager(models.Model):
    mgrname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
class Salesperson(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mgr_name = models.ForeignKey(SalesMgr,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class SalesList(models.Model):
    list_description = modesl.CharField(max_length=100)
    list_members = models.ManyToManyField('Salesperson', through='Manager')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: If I add the "through", how would I access the mgrname?

Comment: Yes, for an instance of SalesList will be : item.list_members.all()  that will return a list of managers.